# Image viewer with color management?

Tags: color

I usually use XnView MP as a reference viewer, since I thought Windows Photos and LXImage-Qt doesn't support it. However, I ran across [this test](http://displaycal.net/icc-color-management-test/) today. It seems that XnView MP doesn't support color management at all, as the `sRGB_Gray.jpg` looks red with text saying the viewer doesn't support it (it should look gray).

Can anyone recommend a free (open source preferred), cross-platform image viewer that supports color management?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly overkill as it aims to be a full photo processing workflow but [Darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) provided full [color management](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/color_management.html) for camera, monitor & output formats.

It is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform

When viewing images & collections:

> Pressing the  button on the right side of the bottom panel lets you
>   define the color profile of your monitor. You can either set this to
>   “system display profile” (default) and let darktable enquire the
>   system's display profile, or alternatively set it to one of the ICC
>   profiles located in $DARKTABLE/share/darktable/color/out and
>   $HOME/.config/darktable/color/out. $DARKTABLE is used here to
>   represent your chosen darktable installation directory and $HOME your
>   home directory.